# How to loop in Ansible over registerd result and selecting specific node?

Tags: ansible

i am registering a result from a specific SQL query:

```
- name: Output Result
  debug:
    var: result.query_result[0]
```

I get a long list that looks like this:

```
 {
    "result": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "query_result": [
            [
                {
                    "C": "",
                    "CHID": "",
                    "DESCRIPTION": "",
                    "EXPECTED_VALUE": "",
                    "HOST": "",
                    "SAP_NOTE": "",
                    "VALUE": ""
                },
                {
                    "C": "",
                    "CHID": "M0005",
                    "DESCRIPTION": "Generated with",
                    "EXPECTED_VALUE": "",
                    "HOST": "",
                    "SAP_NOTE": "1969700",
                    "VALUE": "SQL: \\HANA_Configuration_MiniChecks\\\"\""
                }
            ]
        ],
        "rc": 0,
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": []
    }
}
```

How can I output only this part if he exists:

```
    {
        "C": "",
        "CHID": "M0005",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Generated with",
        "EXPECTED_VALUE": "",
        "HOST": "",
        "SAP_NOTE": "1969700",
        "VALUE": "SQL: \\HANA_Configuration_MiniChecks\\\"\""
    }
```

The location of the above node can change, so i can't specifically target it.

Comment: the `query_result` is a list, it will contain only those 2 items, but the order may change? its better if you explain how to filter the desired row/item from the list

Comment: Hi @ilias-sp, if ["CHID": "M0005"] exist than show.

Comment: thanks for clarification, i posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `json_query` to filter the item that has key/value: `"CHID": "M0005"`

full playbook example to demonstrate:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    query_result:
    - C: ''
      CHID: ''
      DESCRIPTION: ''
      EXPECTED_VALUE: ''
      HOST: ''
      SAP_NOTE: ''
      VALUE: ''
    - C: ''
      CHID: M0005
      DESCRIPTION: Generated with
      EXPECTED_VALUE: ''
      HOST: ''
      SAP_NOTE: '1969700'
      VALUE: 'SQL: \HANA_Configuration_MiniChecks\""'
    - C: ''
      CHID: 22M00051231
      DESCRIPTION: Generated with2121
      EXPECTED_VALUE: ''
      HOST: ''
      SAP_NOTE: '1969700444'
      VALUE: '444SQL: \HANA_Configuration_MiniChecks\""'

  tasks:
  - set_fact: 
      filtered_item: "{{ query_result | json_query('[?CHID == `M0005`]') }}"

  - debug:
      var: filtered_item
```

in your case, the json_query should look like:

```
  - set_fact: 
      filtered_item: "{{ result.query_result | json_query('[?CHID == `M0005`]') }}"
```

Please note that if the list may have multiple items matching the condition, they will all be added to the `filtered_item`. To make sure you get only the first, you can pass the result to `first`:

```
  - set_fact: 
      filtered_item: "{{ query_result | json_query('[?CHID == `M0005`]') | first }}"
```

Comment: it is working :-) many thanks for your quick support.